# What is this vine/crawler growing in my yard?

Tags: identification

I noticed that next to my garden box (not from it, and not climbing into it) I have this vine?  Maybe a crawler?  I'm not sure technically what this would be called.

What is this?  Any thoughts?  It's the three-lobed leave vine.  Looks like some of the leaves are purple-ish, but mostly green.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: what part of the world do you live in?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. This is coastal North Carolina in the united states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's an ivy leaved morning glory (*Ipomoea hederacea*).

[image]

Comment: Those leaves do look similar, although I haven't noticed any flowering.  How would that have gotten in my yard??

Comment: I really don't know... I don't think birds or other animals eat them. Maybe water dispersal? But I'm from the roughly the same area as you, and I see them around here. I have also seen those mottled purple leaves. I think that the question, _how are morning glories dispersed?_ would be a good one (to ask seperately) for this SE.